# проблема с innerHTML

Tags: javascript, php, html

Есть такой код

```js
render(thisTab, false).then((html) => {
  window.el.info.innerHTML = html;
  let orderList = document.querySelector('#ordersList');
  renderOrd().then((orders) => {
    for (let order in orders) {
      let ord = orders[order];
      orderList.innerHTML +=
        `<div class="orderItem" data-good="${ord.id}>
            <img src="./goods/${ord.img}" alt="">
            <div class="orderInfo">
                <div class="orderName">Карты</div>
                <div class="orderDesc">Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Praesentium accusamus expedita sit, minus odit in!</div>
                <div class="orderCost">69₽</div>
            </div>
        </div>`;
    }
  });
});
```

в нем через функцию render приходит html, который вставляется в блок.
Затем через функцию renderOrd приходит такой массив с товарами

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

далее идет перебор этого массива
Но вместо ожидаемого   и тп
вставляется это[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему ссылка совершенно не такая???

Comment: <div class="orderItem" data-good="${ord.id}"> надо было закрыть кавычку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Почему ссылка совершенно не такая???

Вероятно, потому что вы выше не закрыли кавычки у атрибута `data-good`.

`<div class="orderItem" data-good="${ord.id}>`